# Issues with Skyperious

Tags: python

I am trying to install [Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/index.html) on Ubuntu 13.10, I have installed all the required dependencies, my python version is Python 2.7.5+.

When I run the following code from terminal

```
python main.py
```

Nothing happens. Not even any errors. I am in the correct directory and have given 777 permission to the main.py

What could be wrong? I am clueless

Comment: if you start the program like that `777` is not necessary read permissions on the file is the only requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 (32bit) the steps indicated [here](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/) will not work. Even if you additionally install python-dev (which seems to be needed by PIP).

The problems seems to be PIP which probably collides with the replacement functionality provided by [Pillow](http://python-pillow.github.io/) (already installed).

The base installation on 13.10 should therefore be:

```
sudo apt-get install wx2.8-i18n libwxgtk2.8-dev libgtk2.0-dev python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools
```

Don't install python-pip as 1.4 is an old version, instead do:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O - | sudo python
```

Don't install using the requirements.txt, as that includes the old PIP:

```
sudo pip install pyparsing python-dateutil Skype4Py XlsxWriter
```

And get the source:

```
wget http://erki.lap.ee/downloads/Skyperious/skyperious_3.2-src.zip
unzip skyperious_3.2-src.zip
cd skyperious_3.2
```

The problem is that the `skyperious2.sh` file has `\r\n` line-endings and `/bin/sh` cannot handle those. (You can look at the actual bytes in the different files with `od -c filename`,
in the original you will see the `\r` before the `\n`.)
So do:

```
tr -d '\r' < skyperious.sh > skyperious2.sh
chmod 755 skyperious2.sh
./skyperious2.sh
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I agree that, but running that file just gives error as it it appends an ^M at the end and I should open vi editor and do :set ff=unix everytime. And even fixing that did not help.

Comment: As I said, the error is as follows :$ sh skyperious.sh 
/src/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directoryous_3.2
.... But the file is there in the /src path. And if I open skyperious.sh in VI i can see ^M as end of all the lines. So it is DOStoUbnuntu conversion is what it is missing I felt.

Comment: @kingmakerking In what directory did you install because `/src` sounds a bit strange as base directory. The line endings should not bother Python it handles both on both platforms. But the problem is the .sh file, I'll test something and update the answer

Comment: @kingmakerking Updated the answer, with the translated script things started for me without a problem.

Comment: Even after running Skyperious2, nothing happened, nothing opened. I am expecting a GUI to open. Am I wrong? I dont think so

Comment: @kingmakerking No for me the GUI opens, see answer. In what directory is this located. Is it on a network share?

Comment: Not a shared directory. I alone us this laptop of mine and no strings attached. No GUI still :(

Comment: @kingmakerking Did you double check the requirements for Debian/Ubuntu [here](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/) several packages need to be installed ( wx2.8-i18n libwxgtk2.8-dev libgtk2.0-dev python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools python-pip) and run sudo pip install -r requirments. ?

Comment: Double checked it again.Everything installed. Also sudo pip install -r requirments.txt ( as there is no file called requirement. This also gave the message as Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade)...Still no luck :(

Comment: @kingmakerking Sorry, I am at the end of ideas as well. I have a lot of (python) libraries installed on my system, so if there is something missing in the install I might not notice. But I would expect the program to throw an error in that case.

Comment: @kingmakerking I was able to reproduce the problem on a fresh 13.10, and fix it. Just updated the Answer.

Comment: Tons of thanks to you. I can see Skyperious GUI and normal functioning now. I won't erase the test messages which we were trying yesterday ;).